# Twig Templates not extending

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have just setup a apache server and configured twig. I have two template files one called `base.html.twig` which has the core template elements and dashboard with blocks that correspond to the `base.html.twig`

dashboard.html.twig

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <p class="important">
        Welcome on my awesome homepage.
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

However when I browse to `dashboard.html.twig` I just see plain html showing all of the code above. Have I misconfigured something?

I am sure it's something simple so I thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You mention that you've configured Twig. Could you show that configuration?

Comment: `"when i browse to dashboard.html.twig"` Wait, how are you accessing it? What about the Symfony2 tag? Are you using that framework?

Comment: Try AcmeHelloBundle::base.html.twig

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly "browse" to a twig file, it needs to be parsed and rendered by php objects using classes from Twig libraries.

see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation

Answer (score -1):

To use twig you need PHP installed too. Also you would need [Twig PHP library](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) to parse twig templates.

Comment: Thanks, I have installed the twig library and php. do i need to put anything else at the top of my templates. References to the library etc?

Comment: Use PHP files to parse and display Twig templates, do not open them directly with browser.